# How to return a from json converted array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, json

The following code works fine(!), i wnat to moved it into a own function, but i cant return the from json converted Array (last line). What im doing wronng?

```
    public Array jsonToArray(String json) {

    JSONObject myjson = null;
    try {
        myjson = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONArray the_json_array = null;
    try {
        the_json_array = myjson.getJSONArray("profiles");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int size = the_json_array.length();
    ArrayList<JSONObject> arrays = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        JSONObject another_json_object = null;
        try {
            another_json_object = the_json_array.getJSONObject(i);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        arrays.add(another_json_object);
    }

    JSONObject[] jsons = new JSONObject[arrays.size()];
    arrays.toArray(jsons);

    return Array jsons;
}
```

I think the Problem is the Type, but im completely new in JAVA... Im getting the error: 'Not a statement'. What is the meaning and the Solution?

Comment: `return Array jsons;` isn't valid syntax... `return jsons;` is, but it's unclear if that is what you want

Comment: The above code does not compile

Comment: Yeah, the code does not, in fact, "work fine" unless it actual runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public JSONObject[] jsonToArray()
```

As well as

```
return jsons;
```

Or, why not return the `ArrayList<JSONObject>`, why bother with another conversion?

Though, ideally, returning an actual JSONArray object instead of a Java array of JSONObject makes more sense.

Such as

```
return myjson.getJSONArray("profiles");
```

Or, one step further, actually *parsing* out the values of the JSON you want into your own Java classes?

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
return jsons;
```

And also correct the return type, you have `Array` there, I don't see that type defined anywhere in your code, and there is no such type in java, you probably wanted `JSONObject[]`, so the first line of the method will be:

```
public JSONObject[] jsonToArray(String json) {
```

Comment: Hmm, doesnt work, too. i tried: "return jsons;" If i move the mouse over the return statement i get: Incompatible types; Required List; Found: org.json.JSONObject[]

Comment: @hannsworst You need to replace `Array` with `JSONObject[]`